# MooTools - Check if Class has event

Tags: mootools, mootools-events

I want to set a default function for an event of a *Class* and need to check attached events of *Class* **instance**.

As i found out, *Events* implementations have `$events` property to store events and i could check it. Is it a better way?

Comment: that's pretty much the only thing you can do. its not API but it's there to stay so it is safe to use. you can do `Events.prototype.has = function(type){ return type in this.$events };` then any class with the mixin you can do if (!instance.has('ready')) instance.addEvent('ready', fn);` etc. optional second arg can be an exact callback